# How to combine column from multiple text files?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract and combine a certain column from a bunch of text files into a single file as shown.

`File1_example.txt`

```
A   123   1
B   234   2
C   345   3
D   456   4
```

`File2_example.txt`

```
A   123   5
B   234   6
C   345   7
D   456   8
```

`File3_example.txt`

```
A   123   9
B   234   10
C   345   11
D   456   12
```

...

..

.

`File100_example.txt`

```
A   123   55
B   234   66
C   345   77
D   456   88
```

How can I loop through my files of interest and paste these columns together so that the final result is like below without having to type out 1000 unique file names?

```
1   5   9   ...  55
2   6   10  ...  66
3   7   11  ...  77
4   8   12  ...  88
```

Comment: @KenWhite I'm trying to find a way to join these files without having to type out hundreds of unique file names.

Comment: Do all the files have the same length?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, all same length

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
paste File[0-9]*_example.txt | awk '{i=3;while($i){printf("%s ",$i);i+=3}printf("\n")}'
```

**Example:**
File1_example.txt:

```
A   123   1
B   234   2
C   345   3
D   456   4
```

File2_example.txt:

```
A   123   5
B   234   6
C   345   7
D   456   8
```

Run command as:

```
$ paste File[0-9]*_example.txt | awk '{i=3;while($i){printf("%s ",$i);i+=3}printf("\n")}'
```

Output:

```
1 5 
2 6 
3 7 
4 8
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested below code with **first 3 files**

```
cat File*_example.txt  | awk '{a[$1$2]= a[$1$2] $3 " "} END{for(x in a){print a[x]}}' | sort

1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12
```

1) use an awk array, `a[$1$2]= a[$1$2] $3 " "` index is column1 and column2, array value appends all column 3.

2) `END{for(x in a){print a[x]}}` travesrsed array `a` and prints all values.

3)use `sort` to sort the output.

Answer (score 1):

when `cat`ing you need to ensure the file order is preserved, one way is to explicitly specify the files

```
cat File{1..100}_example.txt | awk '{print $NF}' | pr 4ts' '
```

extract last column by `awk` and align using `pr`