# Combine count files into one file and keep zero values

Tags: bash, awk, file-processing

I have multiple count files that look like this:

```
 File1.tab
 6       10      0
 49      0       53
 15      0       15
 0       0       0
 0       0       0
 0       0       0
```

Other file:

```
File2.tab
 3       1       2
 29      0       29
 4       0       4
 0       0       0
 0       0       0
 0       0       0
```

I have over 30 files and I want to combine the second column of each file into one big file.

I know this question have already been asked and I found a similar here [How to combine column from multiple text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415489/how-to-combine-column-from-multiple-text-files)

I used the answer from previous question for my problem:

```
paste  *.tab | awk '{i=2;while($i); {printf("%d ",$i);i+=3}printf("\n")}'
```

The problem is that zero values are not printed, I get something like this:

```
10 1
```

and I want something like this:

```
10 1
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

I cheked the printf format specifiers, but none works. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You picked a bad "answer" to build on. Try this:

```
paste  *.tab |
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=3) printf "%s%s", (i>2?OFS:""), $i; print ""}'
```

Comment: thanks Ed Morton. Your answer works. Could you explain more about the code?

Comment: this part (i>2?OFS:"")

Comment: its a ternary opeartor (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It puts the OFS value in front of the current field for every field after the first one.